# Connect to router periodically fails on Win7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have such trouble with WIndows 7.

`ping.exe` screenshoot, apologies for the Russian.

[image]

And it's exactly Windows 7, because I changed network adapter, cable, switch port on router, and connect on other computers in LAN all works fine.

Network adapter now is D-Link DFE-520TX, and drivers are updated.

Comment: Are you pinging an IP address or a host name??? I'm not sure how anyone could answer this question with accuracy without understanding written Russian. Wireshark is a good tool for inspecting TCP/IP packets for the most accurate answer, otherwise this seems way to broad why some host would periodically not respond to ICMP packets.

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator
I'm pinging IP adress 192.168.1.1, it is the address of router gateway.
"Превышен интервал ожидания запроса." means "Request timed out.".
I'll try Wireshark, thank you.

Comment: Look at the router logs too or enable verbose logging and then check it. Otherwise, yes, run WireShark or some equivalent TCP/IP capturing tool from the Win7 client with the issue and see what you see at the packet level.

Answer (score 0):

#### Connect to router periodically fails

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help